# User Can Transfer records which they don't own

Tags: sharing, configuration, sharing-rule, criteria-based-sharing

I am facing one strange issue.

Issue : Users are able to transfer account which is not owned by them

Scenario :

Account is Set to Public Read Only under OWD.
Record access given to manager hierarchy using Manager Group.

I have created a Permission set to transfer Record ownership.

Now when User B trying to update Account A which is owned by some one else, he is getting insufficient access issue which is fine.

But without having the edit access when he is trying to update the ownership of same record , he is able to do so.

Is that expected?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Does the profile of the user have Transfer Record permission and Edit access for the object?

Comment: Yes. They have. I was referring to the article you have shared under answer and this one : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000327372&type=1. Here it's mentioned like this : Users can have the ability to transfer records to which they have edit access, including changing Account ownership.

Comment: I hope the article was referencing even though user have edit access they were not able to transfer the records. But the article which I shared gives you the clear understanding of it. You can try my removing the Transfer Record permission  and check.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Yes, I have already tried that before posting the question . The two link confused me a bit.                                                                                                                                   
Trying is to allow user and manager(Same Team ) to transfer Account owner and it should not possible if it's a different team.
Based on the article you have shared, If transfer access gives ability to transfer all records(Edit access) then they can transfer other team's record.                                  
Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

To change the owner of the record  we may not need edit access for the record. If the user has Transfer Record permission and Edit access for the object (Need not be Record) then they will be able to change the owner of the record.

Please find the below help [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_about_transfer.htm&type=5) for the same.